# In ELF, is it possible to specify a mapping of a physical memory region?

Tags: c, linux, elf

In ELF, is it possible to specify a mapping of a physical memory region?

I have a software that needs to access memory that is located in a fixed region of physical memory address space. Currently, I do that by opening `/dev/mem` and `mmap()`ing this region to virtual address space.

The disadvantage of that is that I don't know where `mmap()` will put the mapping in virtual address space. So I always need to compute the pointers into the region by offsetting from the start of the mapping. This is very inconvenient - I'd rather have the linker to do the mapping for me at program startup, and fixing up my pointers correspondingly.

Comment: You can give `mmap` an address where you would like your mapping to be. It is treated more as a suggestion so you would still have to check whether it actually listened to you and recover if it didn't (assert?).

Comment: The point is, I don't want to have to come up with a fixed virtual address (which can also fail to be satisfied, as you say) - the OS should just make one for me, and the linker should fix up the pointers.

Comment: I think what is usually done is that you declare a (packed) struct describing what's in the memory and you assign a variable with a pointer to that struct to whatever pointer mmap gave you. And then you access it through a pointer to a struct, it is convenient enough. There is no facility in the ELF format to specify anything about physical memory, so for a literal reading of your question, the answer is a simple NO.

Comment: In principle, it should be possible to tell the linker to reserve some specific region of *virtual* memory, and then at runtime you can mmap `/dev/mem` into that region with `MAP_FIXED`.  Probably you'd specify some custom section in the linker script.  I don't know how this will interact with ASLR, though; you might have to disable it, which IMHO would be too high a price to pay.

Comment: @NateEldredge that is a very good idea, I was too stupid to come up with that. Will investigate :-)

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of memory regions into one process' virtual memory map is not a characteristic of ELF (ELF is just a format to specify memory regions only)  You need to dig on how the operating systems provides you the regions when loading an ELF binary.  For this:

- Check the `mmap(2)` system call and friends.  This is the basic call to load a memory segment and associate it with the contents of a file.  This is what the dynamic linker (`ld.so` in many systems) uses to load a program segment into memory.  It is used by the `dlopen(3)` library routine below.
- Check the `dlopen(3)` library function.  This is the high level function that calls the dynamic linker functionality to load and resolve (link) the unsatisfied references at runtime, once the loading program is running.  This is used to load automatically the shared libraries a program uses (it is called by `ld.so` described abobe) and map all the segments into the virtual address space of the process.
- Check the `exec*(2)` family of system calls to see how the operating system loads a program itself into memory.  This is the call that loads and starts executing a new program into the system.

The `mmap(2)` system call *allows you to specify the starting virtual address* (which should not be allocated by the system for other purposes already) or let the system to select the most appropiate.

Dig on the manual pages!! :)

Comment: I think my question was not posed clearly enough. What I'm after is I want to use the dynamic linker (I failed to mention that word explicitly, I only said "program startup") to map that region for me, and then fix up my pointers.

Comment: @JoSo, then use the library documented in the `dlopen(3)` function.  You can load a dynamic object, search for identifiers on it (introspection) and execute/access objects in the shared library as you need.